# perl how to remove last '_'?

Tags: regex, perl

In perl, how to write this regex ?

```
my $line = "job_name_1_" ; #end with '_'

$pattern = "_$"; # tried "\_$", still doesn't work

if($line =~ m/$pattern/){
    # remove last "_" ?
}

-#output should be "job_name"
```

how to do this ?

Comment: Did you mean "output should be "job_name_1""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$test = "test_";
$test = $1 if($test=~/(.*)_$/);
print $test
```

Comment: Yes but the OP asked to remove the last _ without specifying whether this is also the last character before the string, unless I am mistaken. And also in the case you mention you don't need to "eat" all other characters to get there. See @Kurt S answer.

Comment: @TLP, ... except those that contains a newline.

Answer (score 6):

To remove the last underscore character, you just need to do this:

```
$line =~ s/_$//;
```

Comment: This answer only removes the underscore if it's the last character on the line. If you want to remove the last underscore that appears anywhere in the string, look at @FailedDev's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$subject =~ s/_(?=[^_]*$)//;
```

Sorry if someone else has also posted this :)

Comment: It's so funny with the latency :) I immediately corrected it but IT WAS TOO LATE IT SEEMS! :)

Comment: That can remove more than just the last underscore.

Comment: @ikegami No it can't :) Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

To remove a trailing underscore: (`foo__` ⇒ `foo_`, `foo_bar` ⇒ `foo_bar`)

```
$line =~ s/_\z//;
```

To remove all trailing underscores: (`foo__` ⇒ `foo`, `foo_bar` ⇒ `foo_bar`)

```
$line =~ s/_+\z//;
```

To remove the last underscore: (`foo__` ⇒ `foo_`, `foo_bar` ⇒ `foobar`)

```
$line =~ s/_(?!.*_)//s;

$line =~ s/^.*\K_//s;
```